# Windows Phone Button Press Effect

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm Building a very basic game for windows phone based on one I created for iOS. In iOS there is a event for when the screen is pressed. I have looked and cannot find a equivalent in windows phone so have decided to use a large button placed over the entire of the view however i have the issue that when i press the button it fills out in the accent colour. i have tried changing the clickmode .ect to solve this as suggested in some older posts for windows phone 7 however none of these seem to be working. Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a better solution for my requirements. 
Realised that if on the root of the application page i can set a Tap event to fire code so his works like touchesBegan on iOS